# API requires 3 certificates - how to connect to it?

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, client-certificates

I need to connect to API that requires me to upload them 3 certificates and download 3 certificates. And then use them for requests.

How to do it from the C# side? How to utilize those certificates?
There is absolutely no examples or explanations on API side.

Where can I read more on this?

Thank you in advance for any guidelines.

Here are the certificates:
[image]

Comment: It is just a MutualTLS connection with 2 certificates, nothing more. The only thing to do is to use a [httpclienthandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=net-6.0) to provide your client certificate and send it to the Citi API URL. That's all. The example in link is quite complete. Just use `ClientCertificates` property of `httpclienthandler` to provide your client certificate.

Comment: It does *not* appear to be "just a mutual TLS connection", it appears to be mutual TLS plus something else. There is no way to guess what that something else is, you will have to back up and find more and better documentation.